# Problems with linking of obj files from g++ with d files

Tags: d

I am trying to use a c++ function out of a d program after the basic example [here](http://dlang.org/cpp_interface.html).

I am using the standard d compiler and the current version of the TDM gcc mingw package.

To convert the *.o file from the elf32 format to omf32 i use objconf `objconv -f
omf test.o testCpp.obj`.

When i try to link it i get the error

```
>dmd test.d testCpp.obj
OPTLINK (R) for Win32  Release 8.00.12
Copyright (C) Digital Mars 1989-2010  All rights reserved.
http://www.digitalmars.com/ctg/optlink.html
testCpp.obj(testCpp)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined __ZSt4cout
testCpp.obj(testCpp)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined __ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_
T0_ES6_
testCpp.obj(testCpp)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined __ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5
_PKc
testCpp.obj(testCpp)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined __ZNSolsEi
testCpp.obj(testCpp)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined __ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E
testCpp.obj(testCpp)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined __ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
testCpp.obj(testCpp)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined __ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
test.obj(test)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined ?foo@@YAHHHH@Z (int cdecl foo(int ,int ,int ))
--- errorlevel 8
```

If i try to link the converted `libstdc++.a` file to it it even gets worse.

I am using windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in your C++ function uses symbols from the C++ standard library (such as cout), which is not linked with D programs. You'd need to either link the C++ standard library with the D program (although it's unclear how that'd work together with the D runtime or how you'd get GCC's C++ runtime to work with DMC's C runtime), or remove all uses of the C++ standard library from your C++ code.

You may find it easier to use a C++ DLL with a D executable instead.